# Gorm extra where 1 <> 1 in many2many

Tags: go, many-to-many, go-gorm

I have two models (structs). `User` and `Group`. Those models have many to many relationships.

When I try to create query `db.Unscoped().Model(&group).Related(&users, "Users")` this returns:

```sql
SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN user_groups ON user_groups.owner_id = users.id WHERE (1 <> 1)
```

The entities are:

```golang
type Group struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID    uint   `json:"id"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Users []User `gorm:"many2many:user_groups;association_jointable_foreignkey:owner_id"`
}
```

```golang
type User struct {
...
    Groups  []Group `gorm:"many2many:user_groups;association_jointable_foreignkey:group_id"`
}
```

Handler

```golang
users := []models.User{}
group := models.Group{}

db.Unscoped().Model(&group).Related(&users, "Users")
```

I don't know the reason to generate extra `where`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed.

I have eliminated `gorm.Model` in struct:

```
type Group struct {
    ID    uint   `json:"id"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Users []User `gorm:"many2many:user_groups;association_jointable_foreignkey:owner_id"`
}
```

And In the query:

```
db.Model(&group).Related(&users)
```

Regards.